# Where can I get more Growth Eggs?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

When I started playing, I was given a **Growth Egg** as a launch bonus. I used it on Cloud and it trivialized the first few areas to have him at level 7 right out of the gate, but once I picked up Rydia, dragging her along was painfu. It took about 4 attempts to get her to survive one map and get her to level 3 (at which point, it seems she was mostly fine and able to live long enough to keep getting XP).

I'm really am not looking forward to doing it all over again when I pick up Cecil and Tifa with my next few batches of Stamina; having another Growth Egg to get over that initial "everything one-shots you" hump would be great, but I can't figure out how on earth to get anymore. Are they IAP only? Do they come from the Relic draw? or somewhere else?

Comment: In addition to growth eggs, just run them through a level 1 dungeon to start with.  The low dungeons are VERY low stamina costs and they aren't in danger of dying.  The first few levels are quick even at low dungeons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to obtain growth eggs is from the Sunday daily dungeon (Glade of Wisdom - increased XP). They are completion rewards in Glade of Wisdom and what type and/or quantity of growth egg obtained is determined by the difficulty:

Easy = 1 Minor Growth Egg
Normal = 2 Minor Growth Eggs
Hard = 1 Lesser Growth Egg

Since these are completion rewards, you can spam the dungeon all day (as much as your stamina will let you) and stock up on them.

Answer (score 0):

Growth Eggs appear to be availiable as rewards for completion/mastery of certain battles; I just saw a reward of 15 Eggs for completing Level 6 of the Mount Ordeals Challenge that's currently running.